# Automation for an android app

Tags: android, automation

Which language or program do I use to automate an android application based on conditions.
So basically it needs to be a smart bot which will automate this android application.
If it is an android game how do i make it so if it sees an item at a defined location , it needs to do something, else it will log out.
Can this be automated without errors and without me having to relaunch anything?
Is this hard to be done?

Comment: If you are trying to test an app, use UiAutomator from the Android SDK tools. If you are trying to do this sort of automation from an app, that's not possible, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this if the app is installed on bluestacks, then I make an application for windows which analyze the pixels which previously inputted for an item, and if pixels correspond at 95% it would do something?